# How to concatenate every two csv file from a single folder in to one csv file each?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a folder with files in the format **p1_1001.csv, p1_1002csv, p2_1001.csv, p2_1002.csv...**

They are part1 and part 2 data for a single candidates **1001,1002...**

I want to combine p1 and p2 for each candidate. That is, generate a single csv file for each candidate.. *1001,1002,1003..* from that folder where the data for both parts are stored.
So the part one is trail numbers from 1-49 and part 2 is from 50 to 99.I want to concatenate  PI with p2 without the headers of p2.So getting one csv file for partcipant 1001 from trial 1 to 100 in one folder

I have tried working with glob but I am unable to get it working. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: How far have you got? Are you able to share the code to date and where you are getting stuck?

Comment: How do you generate the "single csv for each candidate"? Is it simply by concatenating the csv contents? Does the content of the csv matter? e.g. if both p1_1001.csv and p2_1001.csv contain header, does the final 1001.csv need to contain at most one header?

Comment: So the part one is trail numbers from 1-49 and part 2 is from 50 to 99.I want to concatenate  PI with p2 without the headers of p2.So getting one csv file for partcipant 1001 from trial 1 to 100 in one folder.@AdityaSantoso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it using **glob** and it should work fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

_candidates = ['1001', '1002'] # All candidates
_candidate_files = [(candidate, glob.glob('./*{}.csv'.format(candidate))) for candidate in _candidates]

for candidate in _candidate_files:
    df = []
    for file in candidate[1]:
        file_df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df.append(file_df)
    df = pd.concat(df, axis=0)
    df.to_csv(candidate[0] + '.csv')
```

For all the candidates you want the final df for, populate the list. This is ofcource assuming **p1** and **p2** have aligned columns.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas here:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

# step 1: list all csv in that directory
mypath = './foo/bar' # this should point to the directory where the csv resides
csvs = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if ('csv' in f and  isfile(join(mypath, f)))]    

# step 2: group CSVs that belong to one candidate
groups = {}
for c in csvs:
    (pNum, candidate) = c.split('_')
    if candidate not in groups:
        groups[candidate] = []
    groups[candidate].append(c)


# step 3: read contents for each group, append to one file
for candidate in groups:
    files = groups[candidate]        
    for f in files:
        with open(join(mypath, f) , 'r') as file:
            data = file.read()

        with open(candidate, 'a+') as outFile:                                
            outFile.write(data)
            # if you need to append newline at the end of every segment:
            outFile.write('\n')
```

addendum: if using `pandas` is not an issue, I strongly recommend looking at `pandas.read_csv` as relatively painless and fuss-free way of processing csv. If you operate within `pandas` `DataFrame`, you can also do `pd.concat([df1, df2])`([docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html)) to concatenate csv contents logically